# Navigation Bar is not transforming in RTL mode xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, flyout

I was using a masterdetailpage in my app which was working fine in RTL mode once i added

```
 FlowDirection="{x:Static Device.FlowDirection}"
```

and i set flow direction dynamically in App.cs
but i have to change it to flyoutpage which is working well in RTL but the navigation bar is not transferring to RTL.

hamburger icon is fine

[image]

I've a problem with the navigation bar

[image]

```
//Start of the app in App.cs
 MainPage = new  NavigationPage(new Login() );
//After Successful Login
 Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new  FlyoutMainPage());
// in  FlyoutMainPage()
 NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some limitations about RTL localization in xamarin forms. You could refer to  [Right-To-Left localizations limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/right-to-left#limitations).

`NavigationPage button location, toolbar item location, and transition animation is controlled by the device locale, rather than the FlowDirection property.`

That means you could change the language and region to make it.

And then you have to tell your application that it’s allowed to recognize a right-to-left layout. For iOS, add the right-to-left language in the CFBundleLocalizations section of your Info.plist. Such like the following:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key> 
    <string>ar</string> 
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key> 
    <array> 
        <string>ar</string> 
    </array>
```

For Android, you could add android:supportsRtl="true" to your application tag in your AndroidManifest.xml

For more info, you could refer to [Right-To-Left Localization in Xamarin.Forms](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/right-to-left-localization-xamarin-forms/)

Hope it works for you.